# How to change the default screenshot folder in GNOME 42?

Tags: gnome, screenshot, 22.04

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. I have to change my screenshot directory from `/home/<usr_dir>/Pictures/Screenshots` to another path. I could do this in Ubuntu 20.04, but I am not able to do it in 22.04.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just installed `gnome-screenshot` on 22.04 LTS with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
```

and there appears not to be any option to change the default directory from `Home/Pictures/Screenshots` in this version of GNOME.

**Using Terminal**

However, selecting `gnome-screenshot -h` in terminal provides a help file with this utility, from which can be seen that invoking the tool with `-f, --file=filename` will save the file directly to the file specified.

So then the actual syntax (assuming you have a directory called `screens` under `Downloads` in your `Home` directory) will be:

```
gnome-screenshot -f [myfile]
```

and that will save the screenshot to a file called `[myfile]` in that directory. Change the filename to what you require, of course.

Doing this in a terminal holds no issue, since you can easily use terminal shortcuts to reverse search the terminal at the command line prompt. Specifically, you can find the earlier command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and beginning to type any part of the command to present options, and then change the command as required. Another option would be to use <kbd>↑</kbd> to scroll back through earlier commands, but that might be a bit tedious.

This will of course capture the whole screen in the chosen directory, but there are other options which can be set, such as `--area`, as you will see from the help file.

**Use `dconf-editor`**

An alternative method is to change the path of the autosave directory by using `dconf-editor`.

`dconf-editor` is not installed by default, so to install it open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

You can then run the utility either from terminal with `dconf-editor` or select the GUI directly from *Show Applications*.

Once in the editor, select `apps` and then click *Search "apps" folder* and enter `screenshot` in the search box. Then select `/org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/` from the list presented.

[image: dconf-editor screenshot search]

The next step is to select `auto-save-directory` and disable *Use default value*, after which you can then enter a custom value in the field provided.

Using the example above, enter `/Home/Downloads/screens` (or the path of your choice) and save accordingly.

[image: Custom value in /org/gnome/gnome-screenshot/]

On entry to the utility and at the point of saving the image, you can override the defaults to any folder of your choice (or filename), which will be remembered the next time you use the tool.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply. I have tried the method you specified above and it did work. But I want the same UI that the default screenshot shows. So please do suggest a method that will work like that.

Thanks.

Comment: perhaps you could explain further so I can edit my answer accordingly? If you regard the solution proposed as a suitable work-around, perhaps you would be kind enough [to consider](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) this reference?

Comment: Your welcome. So is there a solution to the problem I mentioned the day before?

Thanks.

Comment: possible solutions are contained in the answer provided. You might wish to [accept and upvote](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) accordingly to help others find the solution.

Comment: I mean is there any other solution, cause I want to use the default UI presented.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way without `dconf` is to create a symlink to the folder where you want to place screenshots, which has the name `Screenshots` and is located in `/home/<user_name>/Pictures`, of course deleting the default folder of screenshots.

Comment: [Changing the auto save directory for screen shots and screen cast in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408611/changing-the-auto-save-directory-for-screen-shots-and-screen-cast-in-ubuntu-22-0) discusses about the same issue and I love the solution by vanadium.
The solution seems to be same as this one and easy to follow.