# How to get back previous screenshot functionality on 22.04?

Tags: screenshot, 22.04

Older versions of Ubuntu allowed us to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print screen</kbd> to prompt the selection of an area and take the screenshot by copying it directly to clipboard.

So, how do we get this back?

I want to stress that the undesirable behaviors of the current screenshot tool are:

- Having to do an **extra click** after selecting the area in order to save the screenshot.
- The image getting **saved** to a folder in addition to just being copied to the clipboard.

Additionally, how to change the default folder for the screenshots? `dconf-editor` does nothing for the new tool.

---

I tried installing `gnome-screenshot` and setting a custom shortcut with the command:

```
gnome-screenshot -a -c
```

It does allow me to select an area, but it does not save it to the clipboard afterwards.

Comment: please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by `dconf-editor` does nothing. I have successfully used it as outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404018/307670)

Comment: gnome-screenshot is not the default tool for 22.04, dconf-editor works if you install and use it (and I would gladly do so) but it does not solve my main issues as I pointed out. In fact the answer you linked clearly did not solve the problem for the OP by reading his comments.

Comment: I'm not sure it matters what is the "default" tool or not.  I think one of the beauties of Linux / Ubuntu is the ability for us to choose what we like.  As for your problem, it's a bit strange to me.  I've just upgraded to 22.04 and the feature that you want "back" is what I now have as default!  I actually want what you now have and it seems like it is just the `gnome-screenshot` program.  So, I just need to map my PrtScn key to `gnome-screenshot`.  (Sorry, I can't solve your problem.  I don't know how I got what you want; it just happened after my upgrade.)

Comment: @Eduardo that said, he accepted the answer in any event... 

Comment: Try the wrapper script around `gnome-screenshot` mentioned in [this comment on the bug report about this problem](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5208#note_1426865)

Comment: @muru the wrapper did work, good to know it is an open issue in the gnome project itself, hopefully it goes somewhere. Do you want to answer this question so I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [muru pointed out in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404753/how-to-get-back-previous-screenshot-functionality-on-22-04#comment2439710_1404753) this is an [open issue in the gnome project](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5208#note_1426865) and there is a workaround.

Here is how I solved it:

1. Install `gnome-screenshot`:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-screenshot
   ```
2. Install `xclip`:

   ```
   sudo apt install xclip
   ```
3. Create the following script:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash  
   TMPFILE=`mktemp -u /tmp/screenshotclip.XXXXXXXX.png`  
   gnome-screenshot -af $TMPFILE && xclip $TMPFILE -selection clipboard -target image/png; rm $TMPFILE || echo ""
   ```
4. Save it wherever you want.
5. Go to Settings → *Keyboard* → *View and Customize Shortcuts* → *Custom Shortcuts*.
6. Add it as shown in the following image:

[image]

---

Now for saving the screenshot to a specific folder, I couldn't find a solution for the default GNOME tool, but if you are going to use `gnome-screenshot` anyway, an option is to create another custom shortcut for printing with `gnome-screenshot`, with a command like this:

```bash
sh -c 'gnome-screenshot -af /path/you/want/it/saved/$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").png'
```

Comment: That script gives me the error `Screenshot.sh: 3: /tmp/screenshotclip.NoqDlClS.png: not found
Missing argument for -f
rm: missing operand` on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Foxes - the code should be ```#!/bin/bash

TMPFILE=`mktemp -u /tmp/screenshotclip.XXXXXXXX.png`

gnome-screenshot -af $TMPFILE && xclip $TMPFILE -selection clipboard -target image/png; rm $TMPFILE || echo ""
```