# Changing the auto save directory for screen shots and screen cast in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: directory, screenshot

I recently switched to Ubuntu 22.04 and I really like its default screenshot UI, but there seems to be no way to change the autosave directory. It saves the pictures to the `$HOME/Pictures/Screenshots` directory and I want it to save them to another directory.
I know there are alternatives such as using `gnome-screenshot` but I want to use the default one.

Please suggest a method to resolve this issue. And please feel free to ask for other additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default screenshot folder in GNOME 42?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403994/how-to-change-the-default-screenshot-folder-in-gnome-42)

Comment: It's not really. This answer simply installs different screenshot tool which is configurable. It doesn't answer how to configure default Ubuntu 22.04 screenshot tool. I personally like the built-in Ubuntu 22.04 tool and would really like to configure the output path.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like this path is hardcoded, at best in a readable configuration file, at worst in binary code. There is no user exposed way to change that path.

As a workaround, you may replace the directory "Screenshots" in the "Pictures" directory by a link pointing to the location where you want to save the images. You could even hide that default directory by creating a text file `.hidden` in the Pictures folder, that contains the line `Screenshots`. For practical purposes, that would achieve what you want, but it remains a workaround.

To achieve that:

1. Delete the directory "Screenshots"
2. [Create a symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/843150/what-happened-to-the-nautilus-feature-create-link-in-ubuntu-16-10-and-newer) with the name "Screenshots" to the directory where you would want the files to be saved.

Now, files saved to `~/Pictures/Screenshots` will, because of the link, actually be written in the directory that link "Screenshots" refers to.

Optionally, to hide "Screenshots"

1. In the text editor, enter a line "Screenshots".
2. Save that file in the directory "Pictures", giving it the name `.hidden`.

The file `.hidden` is in itself hidden, because the name starts with a dot. Any file names included in that file also will be hidden in the file manager.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could please explain your answer more.

Comment: I added steps of what to do to create this effect.

Comment: just a trick...

Comment: @Zagfai I indicated that the path is hardcoded. So yes, anything else than editing source code is just a trick.

Comment: @odigity file an issue to the developers of Gnome Shell. This is not Canonical's doing except for their choice to use Gnome Shell.

Comment: @vanadium - Are you sure?  (I concluded it was Canonical's fault because gnome-screenshot still exists, and installs and works fine - and lets you set the download dir.)

Comment: @odigity Yes I am sure. gnome-screenshot indeed also remains available thus far.

Comment: Does it mean the default screenshot tool does not follow XDG_PICTURES nor any xdg conventions ? ? ?