how to enable the prompt menu for choosing where to save a screenshot, ubuntu 20.04
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal)  on  HP Envy.  The gnome-screenshot utility works through terminal, but it automatically saves in Pictures folder.  Previously, I was using Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) in which this utility was run with just CTRL+M, I could select the area of the screen to capture and a small window appears prompting you to select where you would like to save the screenshot capture. Is this prompt window possible in 20.04 ?

have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408611/changing-the-auto-save-directory-for-screen-shots-and-screen-cast-in-ubuntu-22-0 - it's not exactly what you're asking but is a workaround for where to save.
