# how to change saving directory of screenshots in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: 22.10

when you take a screen shot it gets saved in the pictures folder.

how can i change the screenshot directory to be saved in the downloads folder on Ubuntu 22.10?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the default screenshot folder in GNOME 42?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403994/how-to-change-the-default-screenshot-folder-in-gnome-42)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the auto save directory for screen shots and screen cast in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408611/changing-the-auto-save-directory-for-screen-shots-and-screen-cast-in-ubuntu-22-0)

Comment: Short answer: you cannot. Still you can redirect the files elsewhere by symlinking. Or You could reinstall the old tool.